# how can i reactivate an app on the play console?

Tags: flutter, console, playback

I uploaded my first flutter app to publish on the Google Play Console. Since I wasn't happy with the result, I removed it with the aim of re-uploading it. Can someone please tell me how to get a removed app back?

I had the hope that it would be back after a new release. After the release, the app was approved even though it is considered removed, but everything remains inactive. I would be very happy about your tips. Google seems to have completely stopped support

Answer (score 5):

In the Google Play console:

1. Select *Advanced Settings* in the left nav bar.
2. Under the *App Availability* tab, select *Published*.
3. Click the *Save Changes* button.

Answer (score 1):

Open Google play console .. choose the application then From Release .. Choose Setup>>Advanced settings App Availability .. Choose published then save changes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).